# Creating compressed archives with tar from C++

Tags: c++, linux, system-calls, tar

```
if(cmd == "zip")
        {
            string z = "tar cvf " + destination + "  " + file;
            system(z.c_str());
        }
```

I wanted to compress a file. to a given destination. But what is happening in my case is it makes a compressed file of destination. Like I am using it in Linux, and in Destination I give "Desktop" and in file I give filename. so it only makes Desktop compress file with no extension on Desktop.

Comment: Not so much to do with c++ primarily.

Answer (score 4):

You can do:

```
string z = "tar cvzf " + destination + "/" + file + ".tar.gz  " + file;
```

(the variables, if untrusted, should be sanitized, keeping in mind that `system()` invokes a POSIX shell)

Without the "z", tar creates a `.tar` file, but you have to specify the file name and extension yourself—it's not automatic.

With the "z", it creates a `.tar.gz` file (which is different from a `zip` file—a common `tar` doesn't do `zip` files).

There are other options.
See [tar(1)](https://linux.die.net/man/1/tar) for more details.

---

BTW, a call to the `system` function is technically not a [system call](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/System_call).

Comment: Upvote, but I don't really see a reason to use the `v` in the parameter list, however ;-)

Comment: @cfromme Thanks. The v is copied from the OP.